# Warning with stack trace "No bean factory"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration-dsl

I developed a custom dynamic FTP component to work with spring integration dsl. The component works fine with spring-boot 1.3.0. However, I had to update spring-boot in some of my integrations to use barrier dsl feature, going to 1.5.6.

From now on, I get a warning with the following stack trace, despite the component still works:

```
pool-4-thread-1] o.s.i.expression.ExpressionUtils         : Creating EvaluationContext with no beanFactory

java.lang.RuntimeException: No beanFactory
at org.springframework.integration.expression.ExpressionUtils.createStandardEvaluationContext(ExpressionUtils.java:79)
at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.getEvaluationContext(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:113)
at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.getEvaluationContext(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:99)
at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:169)
at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:157)
at org.springframework.integration.file.DefaultFileNameGenerator.generateFileName(DefaultFileNameGenerator.java:70)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate$1.doInSession(RemoteFileTemplate.java:305)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate$1.doInSession(RemoteFileTemplate.java:283)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:435)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:283)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:273)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:265)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(FileTransferringMessageHandler.java:170)
at net.afferolab.ftp.dsl.handler.DynamicFileTransferringMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(DynamicFileTransferringMessageHandler.java:37)
```

The last row of stack trace indicates my custom component.

This is a part of my custom ftp handler:

```
@Override
public void handleMessageInternal(Message<?> message) throws Exception {
    DynamicSessionFactory.FtpCredentials credentials = new DynamicSessionFactory.FtpCredentials(
            DynamicSessionFactory.FtpProtocol.valueOf(this.evaluateExpression(this.protocolExpression, String.class, message)),
            this.evaluateExpression(this.hostExpression, String.class, message),
            this.evaluateExpression(this.usernameExpression, String.class, message),
            this.evaluateExpression(this.passwordExpression, String.class, message),
            this.evaluateExpression(this.portExpression, Integer.class, message)
    );

    this.dynamicSessionFactory.setCredentials(credentials);
    super.handleMessageInternal(message);
}

private <T> T evaluateExpression(Expression expression, Class<T> expectedType, Message<?> message) {
    ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor<T> expressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor = new ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor<>(expression, expectedType);
    expressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor.setBeanFactory(this.getBeanFactory());

    return expressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor.processMessage(message);
}
```

This is a example of usage inside a flow:

```
.publishSubscribeChannel(ps -> ps
            .subscribe(sf -> sf.handle(DynamicFtp.outboundAdapter()
                .protocolExpression("headers[ftp_info].ftpProtocol")
                .hostExpression("headers[ftp_info].ftpServerUrl")
                .portExpression("headers[ftp_info].ftpServerPort")
                .usernameExpression("headers[ftp_info].ftpUsername")
                .passwordExpression("headers[ftp_info].ftpPassword")
                .remoteDirectoryExpression("headers[ftp_info].ftpDirectory")
                .autoCreateDirectory(true))
            )
 // ...
```

I would like to understand if I should worry with this warning and why the bean factory is not get setting by:

```
expressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor.setBeanFactory(this.getBeanFactory());
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: you should not worry about this stack trace since this exception is created to be logged and not thrown. You can check at `ExpressionUtils.java:79` calling `doCreateContext` that the beanFactory is even annoteated with `@Nullable`. Its a warning for "hey, you should finish building your AbstractExpressionEvaluator!"

I would try changing `expressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor.setBeanFactory(this.getBeanFactory())` for `expressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor.afterPropertiesSet()`. Checking for the source code of `afterPropertiesSet`:

```
@Override
public final void afterPropertiesSet() {
    getEvaluationContext();
    if (this.beanFactory != null) {
        this.messageBuilderFactory = IntegrationUtils.getMessageBuilderFactory(this.beanFactory);
    }

    onInit();
}
```

Since there's no full code from your custom ftp handler, I would assume its `this.beanFactory` is returning null while the context inside `AbstractExpressionEvaluator.afterPropertiesSet` is not